# How to install iftop?

Tags: yum

I tried:

```
root@host [/home]# yum install iftop
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: yum.singlehop.com
 * updates: mirror.wiredtree.com
Setting up Install Process
No package iftop available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So how to do it?

What should I do to be able to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either download the source code and compile the package yourself, or you can downloaded the binary package for your distribution.

Have a look at http://pkgs.repoforge.org/iftop/ as it provides binary packages for RHEL/CentOS and the source.

To install the binary package on CentOS-6 64-bit just do the following:

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/iftop/iftop-0.17-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh iftop-0.17-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: `rpm` can accept a `http` or `ftp` link as the package name. No need to wget. Also, it's best to stick to atleast semi-official repositories like EPEL when possible.

Comment: +1 for both. Can anyone tell me why the 2 answers are different?

Comment: I shorten your instruction to: rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/iftop/iftop-0.17-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

Comment: This repo is not maintained anymore and strongly not recommended to use. Use epel instead!

Find more information on additional rhel / centos/ oel repos here: https://wiki.centos.org/PatrickDGarvey/AdditionalResources/Repositories

Answer (score 15):

`iftop` available in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository:

```
# rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: I did that. Now how to run iftop? I run it and nothing shows up

Comment: after adding repository run this: yum install iftop

Answer (score 4):

For CentOS 7 (fully updated today), install from EPEL repository

```
yum install epel-release -y
yum install iftop -y
```

Not 100% sure, but I think earlier versions require downloading the EPEL repository and installing manually using rpm, then you can just "yum install iftop" (as per other answers)

Comment: Yes it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

For Centos 7 you can do this:

```
rpm -i http://mirror.pnl.gov/epel/7/x86_64/i/iftop-1.0-0.7.pre4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: `sudo yum install libpcap && rpm -i https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/i/iftop-1.0-0.12.pre4.el7.x86_64.rpm` worked for me - also you posted a mirror